# Pentaho - Draw a target line in bar graph using Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

[image: Sample Graph]

I need to draw a target line as shown in the image using Pentaho report designer in a Pentaho Bar Graph.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options.

```
1) using secondary data-source
2) bean-shell scripting
```

let me explain 1st option which is simple,

```
1)once you will double click on chart you will get two options on right side,Primary datasource and secondary datasource.
2)in secondary datasource specify categoty-columns and value-columns the field you want to display.
3)then in bar left side properties go to line options category and give details like line-style= solid, line-series-color=orange(specify colorcode) etc..
```